# How do I put a dictionary key pair into a picker in xamarin forms and retrieve the key value from the picker?

Tags: xamarin.forms, dropdown, code-behind, picker, bindable

I have a xaml file where I put the picker in and a code behind to populate it. The code used below:

```
 Dictionary<string, int> list = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                { "Aqua", 6},
                { "Red", 1 },
                { "Silver", 2 },
                { "Teal", 3 },
                { "White", 4 },
                { "Yellow", 55 }
            };
            foreach (string item in list.Keys)
            {
                ddlPurpose.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

I am trying to get the value 55 when I select yellow but the only thing I get is 5. I am using this to get the selected value

```
var val1 = ddlPurpose.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var val2 = ddlPurpose.SelectedIndex;
```

Is it even possible to get the key value? Have looked into the BindablePicker but that didn't seem to work at all. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you meant to do is:

```
var pSelectedIndex = ddlPurpose.SelectedIndex;
var selectedKey = list.Values.ElementAt(pSelectedIndex);
```

I would recommend to get familiar with MVVM and in this specific case with [Behaviors](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/). I wrote a small example to demonstrate how it may look using MVVM:

```
public class PickerKeyValueTestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> colors { get; } = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "Aqua", 6 },
            { "Red", 1 },
            { "Silver", 2 },
            { "Teal", 3 },
            { "White", 4 },
            { "Yellow", 55 }
        };

    public List<string> Colors { get; } = colors.Keys.ToList();

    public string SelectedColor { get; set; }

    public void OnSelectedColorChanged()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedColor)) return;
        var selectedValue = colors[SelectedColor];
    }

    // Using PropertyChanged.Fody
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PickerKeyValueTest"
    x:Class="PickerKeyValueTest.PickerKeyValueTestPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PickerKeyValueTestViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout
        Margin="25">
        <Picker
            ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor}">

        </Picker>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This is a great example. Really gave me a base understanding of what I wanted to do and how to do it. To finish it off this other answer has some extra information that might be helpful also. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45799395/7933361